# Using JSON files instead of database?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I've done a bit research around but I was hoping for some more specific advise.

I'm currently building a small web app for myself and some friends to comic book archives with but I'm really struggling with the database structure.

As it currently stands my main database table's field titles are ID, comic_series, issue and location. I have some other tables which relate to the user but aren't relevant right now.

My problem is that I'm finding that I'm going to need a ridiculous amount of fields to hold the information about one comic, for examples start year, writer, penciler, publisher, volume, etc the list goes on really. And I can't help but feel that storing everyone's comic information in one table would be a performance nightmare with a large amount of information especially with information like the order of the pages.

In looking into a program called comicrack I found that it has an XML database that stores in the comic information.

Like so http://pastebin.com/8PtH1hea

So I was thinking about each user having their own JSON file (or XML for that matter) and loading that in when they login in. I can't help but feel like it would be more efficient to only load the information the user needs.

Ultimately my question is in this particular case because of what may become an enormous amount of fields (or tables if I'm normalising correctly) do you think having a JSON file per user sounds like a terrible idea? I'm just unsure what would be more of a performance nightmare. then again if I'm thinking of what's basically a JSON database maybe I should think about going for a full JSON database like Mongo.

Comment: Are you going to be searching by various fields and combinations of fields? If so, you'll want a conventional database. How many entries do you anticipate?

Comment: Hmmmm yeah the user would be querying pretty much any of the fields so I think that's my answer right there.... 30+ fields per comic tbh as I'm planning on tracking page order. I guess it wouldn't be a terrible idea to place a serialise object or json array into mysql for stuff that isn't going to be queried...

Comment: A database would also allow you to search over all your comics / users, something that a file-per-user would make nearly impossible.

Comment: A user's comic collection is completely private to them so it wouldn't be strictly necessary but I definitely see how it could be beneficial especially from the administration side of things...

Comment: Modern databases will easily handle 30 fields per record and 100's of thousands of records, some will easily do millions.

Comment: So as usual it really is just a case of structuring my database properly and I should I fine? lol

Comment: If you are not sure about the number of fields and what fields are used in which tuple, you can use a schema-less key-value store such as MongoDB

Comment: @kidshenlong, yep. You got it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a really bad idea to make them send their file (without saying they could overwrite it).

You could store a file/user on your server maybe.

But having a large number of row in a database is not a problem.

Maybe you could split it in more tables ? (one for writers for instance => get all books for one given writer :D)